# How can I dump an AWS Route53 zone in a BIND-compatible format?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, bind, amazon-route53

I have a zone in Route53 that I need in a BIND-compatible format.

How can I convert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id «zoneid» | \
 jq -r '.ResourceRecordSets[] | "\(.Name) \(.TTL) IN \(.Type) \(.ResourceRecords[] | join("\n"))"'
```

example output:

```
contoso.com. 300 IN A 192.0.2.42
contoso.com. 300 IN A 198.51.100.0.42
contoso.com. 300 IN AAAA 2001:db8:1234::
contoso.com. 300 IN AAAA 2001:db8:5678::
contoso.com. 172800 IN NS ns-1273.awsdns-31.org.
contoso.com. 172800 IN NS ns-729.awsdns-27.net.
contoso.com. 172800 IN NS ns-367.awsdns-45.com.
contoso.com. 172800 IN NS ns-1816.awsdns-35.co.uk.
contoso.com. 900 IN SOA ns-1273.awsdns-31.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
www.contoso.com. 300 IN A 192.0.2.42
www.contoso.com. 300 IN A 198.51.100.0.42
www.contoso.com. 300 IN AAAA 2001:db8:1234::
www.contoso.com. 300 IN AAAA 2001:db8:5678::
```

Answer (score 2):

@MikeyB your answer is great. Sometimes the default output on aws cli is not json, so you need to add --output json to have a successful execution.

```
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id «zoneid» --output json | \
 jq -r '.ResourceRecordSets[] | "\(.Name) \(.TTL) IN \(.Type) \(.ResourceRecords[] | join("\n"))"'
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/574474)